# Create a flag URL column based on country name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, url, request

I have a pandas column with country names as the column.

I need the PNG url for the flags of the country as a separate column. A URL for the US will be like the following,

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1280px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png
```

How can I achieve the same.

here is my dataframe with the country names.

```
0                           Afghanistan
1                               Albania
2                               Algeria
3                               Andorra
4                                Angola
5                   Antigua and Barbuda
6                             Argentina
7                               Armenia
8                             Australia
9                               Austria
10                      Austria-Hungary
11                           Azerbaijan
12                              Bahamas
13                              Bahrain
14                           Bangladesh
15                             Barbados
16                              Belarus
17                              Belgium
18                               Belize
19                                Benin
20                               Bhutan

.......
.......
Name: Entity, dtype: object
```

Comment: http://www.flags.net/

Comment: For `Afghanistan`, what would be the url ? Is it this `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_Afghanistan.svg/1280px-Flag_of_the_Afghanistan.svg.png` ?

Comment: Wikimedia is not providing a flag retrieval API. Their url scheme is not designed for you to be able to get the flag of any country like this.

Answer (score 2):

So looking at Wikipedia for flag links, it doesn't look like there is a unified format for their urls, so you won't be able to just iterate over your Country list to create the column.

Your best bet would be to simply scrape Wikipedia and iterate your country list into the base File:Flag page.  Something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for item in df['Country']:
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_'+str(item)+'.svg'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    df['Flag_Link'] = soup.find('span', {'class':'mw-filepage-other-resolutions'}).findAll('a')[3]['href']
```

I assumed you wanted the 1280X853 links, which is the [3] span. Let me know if you have any questions.